# How to delete current sudoer with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I know that sounds weird. But I need to delete the current user after I setup my playbook properly.

I have a playbook that updates a server and properly configure users and administrators. I use the user given to become `root` and set up `admin` my main sudoer.

I need to delete `ansible_ssh_user` at the end of my playbook only if it is not `root` or `admin` ?

The following solution doesn't work

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root


  tasks:
    - include_vars: secrets.yml

    - name: add admin user
      user: name={{ ADMIN_USERNAME }} password={{ ADMIN_PASSWORD | password_hash('sha512') }} shell=/bin/bash

    - name: delete current sudoer if not admin or root
      user: name={{ ansible_ssh_user }} state=absent remove=yes
      when: ({{ ansible_ssh_user }}!={{ ADMIN_USERNAME }}) or ({{ ansible_ssh_user }}!={{ ADMIN_USERNAME }})
```

it returns :

```
userdel: user admin is currently used by process 23537
```

Comment: can you provide what error you are getting (or whats going wrong) ?

Comment: I don't think is really Ansible-specific; it's more a problem with deleting a user while they're currently logged in, which I don't think is possible in Linux (but https://unix.stackexchange.com would probably be the best source for info there).  The only things I can think of are crazy hacks like "set up a root cron job that deletes this user, and if the user doesn't exist, removes the cron job".

Comment: @XiongChiamiov or maybe rename current sudoer with admin name ?

Answer (score 4):

It's a little late but for future references, I've done this job with these two tasks:

```
# first change the current ssh user to the new user
- name: user | switch current user to {{ new_user }}
  set_fact:
     current_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
     ansible_user: "{{ new_user }}"

# force remove the old user
- name: user | remove current user ({{ current_user }}) if it's not "{{ new_user }}"
  become: yes
  user:
    name: "{{ current_user }}"
    state: absent
    remove: yes
    force: yes
  when: "current_user != new_user"
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try running an [asynchronous shell command](https://support.ansible.com/hc/en-us/articles/201958037-Reboot-a-server-and-wait-for-it-to-come-back) that does the job for you.

```
- name: delete user
  command: sleep 10 && deluser foo
  async: 0
  poll: 0
  ignore_errors: true
```

In *theory* this will work

Comment: same error: `userdel: user pi is currently used by process 20646` command I use : `command: bash -lc "sleep 10s && deluser {{ ansible_ssh_user }}"`